# How to create the Summary Report using groovy in soap ui for Project

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am in the middle of preparing the HTML summary report for my soap ui project using groovy

Using below tear down script I can read the test case status and name but am not sure about for project report since the tear down can be written under the test suite.

`enter code here`
{Code}

```
def failedTestCases = 0

runner.results.each { testCaseResult ->
    def name = testCaseResult.testCase.name
    if(testCaseResult.status.toString() == 'FAILED'){
        failedTestCases ++
        log.info "$name has failed"
        testCaseResult.results.each{ testStepResults ->
            testStepResults.messages.each() { msg -> log.info msg } 
        }
    }else{
        log.info "$name works correctly"
    }
}

log.info "total failed: $failedTestCases"
```

{Code}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tear down option is available even at Test Project Level

I have added a message and ran the project and it was successful

[image]

if you are using SOAPui instead of Ready API

teardown script can be seen below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response @Gaurav khurana  i tried in the tear down but i am not able to get the test suite summary status since my code is related to test suite  tear down script so can you help me to get the test suite count and its status?

Comment: i have edited the answer and added the soapui screenshot as well. check out and if it helps accept this as solution please. In soapui they have put it under different option. click on project then test suites you will see it

Comment: Thanks gaurav for your timely response , yes i can see the tear down now.. but i need to generate summary report for project level including all test suite and cases in the single shot. so can you assist me on this? because current code is returning single ts result alone

Comment: i think for that you can post another question as it will be miss and match. Meanwhile you can accept this solution. Small suggestion i can give is. In teardown script you can get all testsuite names at project level. Then using suite name you can get testcases name and from their status you can generate the report